# Sort a Query of multi-rows in a row with Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to order a query with Linq where I have a Query result in SQL server with several rows, I would like to group it by client where it shows me the information in a single column per year.

The query to handle is as follows:

```
año    mes  Oficina Cliente  Moneda total
--------------------------------------------
2017    3   O1        Cliente1  USD    3250
2017    5   O1        Cliente1  USD    55000
2018    3   O1        Cliente1  USD    7900
2018    4   O1        Cliente1  USD    7900
2018    7   O1        Cliente1  USD    7900
2017    3   O2        Cliente2  EUR    145,7
2017    7   O2        Cliente2  EUR    6000
2017    2   O2        Cliente3  USD    23250
2017    3   O2        Cliente3  USD    2331,64
2017    4   O2        Cliente3  USD    1504,32
2017    5   O2        Cliente3  USD    1504,32
```

You want to present as follows:

```
oficina  cliente  enero   febrero marzo   abril  ....   diciembre total
======== ======== ======= ======= ======= ===== ======= ========= =====
```

I would like to know if there is a way through Linq to obtain the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This too long if put in comment, but I think this can be discussed if any mistake or wrong with this linq, so I put here:

```
    Dim amountPerGroup = From row In table.AsEnumerable
                   Group row By myGroup = New With {
                                                Key .ano = row.Field(Of Integer)("año"),
                                                Key .Oficina = row.Field(Of String)("Oficina"),
                                                Key .Cliente = row.Field(Of String)("Cliente"),
                                                Key .Moneda = row.Field(Of String)("Moneda")
                                           } Into Group
                   Select New With {
                                   myGroup.ano, myGroup.Oficina, myGroup.Cliente, myGroup.Moneda,
                                  .SumJan = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 1, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumFeb = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 2, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumMar = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 3, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumApr = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 4, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumMay = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 5, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumJun = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 6, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumJul = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 7, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumAug = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 8, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumSep = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 9, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumOct = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 10, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumNov = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 11, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0))),
                                  .SumDec = Group.Sum(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(IIf(x.Field(Of Integer)("mes") = 12, x.Field(Of Double)("total"), 0)))}
```

Comment: thanks @usuario11982798, this answer  has been helpful

Answer (score 1):

**- Edited to reflect vb.net**

This might be best done in your presentation layer, such as in Javascript/Html.  The use case for what you're doing is presentational anyways, so I'd really advise looking into that.

But if you really want it done at the business logic layer, then your strategy depends on how you're looking to represent your object.  I'm assuming, however, that you want to deal with strongly typed objects.  If so, then there is a way but you're not going to like it.

First, let's make a class to represent the structure of your sample data.  Of course, you can return the property names to spanish format on your implementation.

```
Class row
    Public year As Integer
    Public month As Integer
    Public office As String
    Public client As String
    Public currency As String
    Public total As Double

    Public Sub New(ByVal y As Integer, ByVal m As Integer, ByVal o As String, ByVal cl As String, ByVal cu As String, ByVal t As Double)
        year = y
        month = m
        office = o
        client = cl
        currency = cu
        total = t
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then let's populate a list with your sample data:

```
Dim rows = New List(Of row) From {
    New row(2017, 3, "O1", "Cliente1", "USD", 3250),
    New row(2017, 5, "O1", "Cliente1", "USD", 55000),
    New row(2018, 3, "O1", "Cliente1", "USD", 7900),
    New row(2018, 4, "O1", "Cliente1", "USD", 7900),
    New row(2018, 7, "O1", "Cliente1", "USD", 7900),
    New row(2017, 3, "O2", "Cliente2", "EUR", 145.7),
    New row(2017, 7, "O2", "Cliente2", "EUR", 6000),
    New row(2017, 2, "O2", "Cliente3", "USD", 23250),
    New row(2017, 3, "O2", "Cliente3", "USD", 2331.64),
    New row(2017, 4, "O2", "Cliente3", "USD", 1504.32)
}
```

*In the future, present your sample data as I just did, you'll make it easier on those helping you.*

Next, we want to represent the structure of your pivoted data:

```
Class pivotedRow
    Public year As Integer
    Public office As String
    Public client As String
    Public currency As String
    Public Jan As Double?
    Public Feb As Double?
    Public Mar As Double?
    Public Apr As Double?
    Public May As Double?
    Public Jun As Double?
    Public Jul As Double?
    Public Aug As Double?
    Public Sep As Double?
    Public Oct As Double?
    Public Nov As Double?
    Public Dec As Double?
End Class
```

To pivot, I'll first group by the key fields that should serve as the fulcrum on which to pivot around.  Then, from the groups I'll select those keys, as well as a calculation for each month that outputs the `total` field of the record that matches that month.

```
Dim result = rows.GroupBy(Function(r) New With {r.year, r.office, r.client, r.currency
}).[Select](Function(g) New pivotedRow With {
    .office = g.Key.office,
    .client = g.Key.client,
    .currency = g.Key.currency,
    .year = g.Key.year,
    .Jan = g.SingleOrDefault(Function(r) r.month = 1)?.total,
    .Feb = g.SingleOrDefault(Function(r) r.month = 2)?.total,
    .Mar = g.SingleOrDefault(Function(r) r.month = 3)?.total,
    .Apr = g.SingleOrDefault(Function(r) r.month = 4)?.total,
    .May = g.SingleOrDefault(Function(r) r.month = 5)?.total,
    .Jun = g.SingleOrDefault(Function(r) r.month = 6)?.total,
    .Jul = g.SingleOrDefault(Function(r) r.month = 7)?.total,
    .Aug = g.SingleOrDefault(Function(r) r.month = 8)?.total,
    .Sep = g.SingleOrDefault(Function(r) r.month = 9)?.total,
    .Oct = g.SingleOrDefault(Function(r) r.month = 10)?.total,
    .Nov = g.SingleOrDefault(Function(r) r.month = 11)?.total,
    .Dec = g.SingleOrDefault(Function(r) r.month = 12)?.total
})
```

You can make this a little easier on yourself by creating a function:

```
Private Function getMonthTotal(ByVal group As IEnumerable(Of row), ByVal month As Integer) As Double?
    Return group.FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.month = month)?.total
End Function
```

Now you can do:

```
Dim result = rows.GroupBy(Function(r) New With {r.year, r.office, r.client, r.currency
}).[Select](Function(g) New pivotedRow With {
    .office = g.Key.office,
    .client = g.Key.client,
    .currency = g.Key.currency,
    .year = g.Key.year,
    .Jan = getMonthTotal(g, 1),
    .Feb = getMonthTotal(g, 2),
    .Mar = getMonthTotal(g, 3),
    .Apr = getMonthTotal(g, 4),
    .May = getMonthTotal(g, 5),
    .Jun = getMonthTotal(g, 6),
    .Jul = getMonthTotal(g, 7),
    .Aug = getMonthTotal(g, 8),
    .Sep = getMonthTotal(g, 9),
    .Oct = getMonthTotal(g, 10),
    .Nov = getMonthTotal(g, 11),
    .Dec = getMonthTotal(g, 12)
})
```

If you don't like this, you can forego static typing and work with something like a DataTable.  I've done similar pivoting using DataTables.  The code is just as complicated, but at least in that situation it's reusable.  If you go that route though, think real hard about whether it's the best option.  In my case, when I used DataTables it was just for my personal use to help view the data during development, not for the eyes of others.

Comment: This is a vb.net question.

Comment: Thanks @Mary.  Don't know why I didn't see that and furthermore why I assumed it was c#.  Ran the code through a converter.